# Javascript: Upload Multiple Files Synchronously

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, meteor

So I have an uploader at the backend (MeteorJS) which I call in the javascript, `upload.send(file, function() {...}` But I've only managed to upload one file. So how do I make it upload multiple files if I am to set the `<input type="file" multiple />` I am thinking of looping the files in the input but I think it will upload all the files simultaneously. I want something that will wait for the first file to be uploaded then start uploading the next one. Help?

Comment: Try use http://www.dropzonejs.com/, see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508438/using-dropzone-js-with-meteor-js

Comment: I followed this one. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131480/javascript-wait-for-function-in-loop-to-finish-executing-before-next-iteration

Answer (score 0):

Use the library upload meteor and configure Synchronously files : https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads